# Why does my neural network consider different features important compared to my decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cart, importance, shapley-value

I built a neural network and a decision tree using very similar data sets (the only difference was the randomness of selecting the training vs testing set). The variables with the highest shapley values in my neural network are completely different from the top node variables in my decision tree. How could this possibly be? Why would these two different models consider different sets of variables to be important?

Comment: Why not? Why are you expecting the two models to behave similarly? They are different models after all, different assumptions, different algorithms, different ways to approximate functions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Indeed they are different. But what specific "difference" of their nature causes them to not agree on what variables are the most important? My intuition tells me they should be the same. For example if a feature split in a classification tree results in higher purity amongst two leaf nodes wouldn't that imply that "crossing" that split value in the neural network would similarly lead to a considerable change in expected neural network output hence it would have a high shapley value?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to spread misinformation on this forum. So for future viewers who see this question I would like to apologize. There was an error in the code of the scaling function that I used for my neural network. It turns out that the Shapley value for my Neural Network are very similar to what the decision tree determines is important. I consider my question resolved.

Comment: I’d still encourage you to look at the stability of the feature importance in your model, as discussed in the links in my answer/comment.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted? That way it will be more prominently marked and people know a solution exists

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to blow your mind, take a bootstrap sample of your data and run it through either model. It is quite likely that the feature importance ranks will be considerably different, even using the exact same model. Frank Harrell discusses this in his 2020 "Why R?" keynote, [available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF1WsYZ94Es&themeRefresh=1).

This is to say that feature importance is rather unstable and should be expected to fluctuate. Formally quantifying this might be difficult, but it is not obvious that the differences you are observing are statistically significant, given the considerable variability.

Comment: [I find it amazing how (some) people seem content to calculate feature importance values without considering uncertainty, even though they wouldn't do that in other contexts.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/631891/247274)

Comment: (+1) I'm going to add a good-natured quibble:  I am trying to imagine what conceptual gyrations would be necessary to conduct a statistical significance test of the difference between different techniques' coefficients.  What null hypothesis and what assumed data generating process would legitimately fit?