# Can Shapley Value Analysis help with this problem?

Tags: churn, shapley-value

Consider a service like Netflix. A drop in user engagement is a leading indicator of churn (users unsubscribing). They try various things to keep people hooked. Other than making engaging content available, they have digital product teams working on improving these three factors:

1. Number of titles watched - by improving the recommendations algorithm, etc.
2. Hours watched - by improving the performance of streaming so that users don't experience buffering and switch off.
3. Frequency of use - by nudging them with notifications of new seasons/episodes on the mobile app, etc.

These efforts cost money which they want to spend judiciously on efforts that deliver the greatest bang for the buck. And they want to reward the teams based on their impact on churn.

Assuming they have weekly data of the above factors and churn over a couple of years, could they use ***Shapley Value analysis*** to attribute a drop in churn to the three factors (and a couple of other variables outside the control of these teams)? And use the attribution results for annual bonus payout and future funding?

Is there something I can read to better understand cases like this? I'm aware of a number of articles that discuss multi-touch attribution for marketing but I'm not sure if they apply equally well to this case which seems to be more of multi-factor attribution.

Comment: Generally, this seems more like a problem of determining how much a factor effects a response. So any kind of dependence analysis can be used, Shapley value is definitely one way to do it. Otherwise, take a look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-machine-learning-models-partial-dependence-ce6b9923034f

Comment: If you're going to look at SHAP values or some other measure of feature importance, please consider the uncertainty in those values, as is discussed in the comments to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/631891/247274) answer.